# How to get Drupal to stop overiding table tag background color

Tags: theming

I'm still working in the default Bartik theme that came with Drupal core. I've put an HTML table inside the body area of a node to organize some information. It is just a vanilla HTML table:

```
<table>
<TR><TD> ... </TD><TD> ... </TD><TD> ... </TD> etc. </TR>
<TR><TD> ... </TD><TD> ... </TD><TD> ... </TD> etc. </TR>
<TR><TD> ... </TD><TD> ... </TD><TD> ... </TD> etc. </TR>
etc.
</table>
```

It shows up on the page with a light blue background. I want the background to be white. Putting an attribute in the table tag: "<table bgcolor = "#FFFFFF">" does not have any effect. It's not that the attribute is completely ignored because if I make it "<table bgcolor = "#000000">" then the background turns black.

I'm guessing that this has something to do with CSS that I do not have access to and is being controlled by the theme. When I look at the settings for Bartik, there is nothing about tables. Am I just stuck with this blue table background until I instal a different theme? Can I expect that most other major themes will allow me to set something as important as this?

Comment: This is a plain CSS question. You don't say how you output the HTML, so the question is a bit vague too.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1114190 . If you cant adjust some of the colors in Bartik by going on the theme settings page make your adjustments by adding css. use !important to force drupal to implement your style and always clear cache by installing the devel module to see current changes.

Comment: "I put HTML code in the page" is not really helpful.  Did you put HTML in a page template, the body content field of some entity type, or did you hack core to get your HTML in the page?

Comment: @FreeRadical, I guess there's a lot I still don't understand about Drupal. When I click the "Edit" tab on the page, I get a box called "Body", where I enter the content of the page in HTML. That's what I mean that I put HTML code on the page. Is that the wrong way to build a page? I don't know what a page template is, but looking around after your question, I see it mentioned on https://www.drupal.org/documentation/theme, so I need to learn about that. I've read about entity types, but had no idea you could put HTML in one, so more to learn there. I did not and will never (I think) hack core.

Comment: @AlyssaGono, this is the second time you've answered my question in a comment! Thank you for that link. It's obviously going to take some work to implement its instructions, but it seems certain to do what I was asking for. It's strange that it's called "How to customize Bartik" because it seems that it's a general instruction on how to customize any theme. Am I wrong about that? Thank you again!

Comment: OK, what you do is the right way to put *content* on a page, but Drupal, by default, don't expect a user to put advanced HTML (like tables) in a body. Look below the body field for a menu called "Text format". If it says "Filtered HTML", select "Full HTML" and resave (you'll have to be "admin" to have access to "Full HTML").